# Django Cannot Create Test Database Permission Denied

Tags: 14.04, permissions, postgresql, django

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with Postgres 9.3, Python 3.0 and Django 1.7.  When I try to debug my application from PyDev, I receive the following:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database
```

Oddly enough, I cannot login to user postgres from command line with the password originally created.  I reset it once last night, and am still unable to do so.

My `pg_hba.conf` is as follows:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
local all postgres peer
local all stbiuser md5
local all all md5
```

My `settings.py` is as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'db',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
    'Host':'127.0.0.1',
    'PORT':'5432'
    }
}
```

How do I remedy the permission denied message? Are there any settings modifications that are required as well?

Comment: Can you try `local all postgres all`?

Answer (score 8):

you user probably does not have permission to create a database, open a terminal and log into postgress as postgress and run the following

```
ALTER USER user CREATEDB;
```

Comment: You can also add the createdb permission when creating a user:

su - postgres dropuser --if-exists user
su - postgres createuser user --createdb